# Convert Mono<Stream<String>> to Flux<String>

Tags: java, java-stream, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a Mono like this `Mono<Stream<String>>` and I want to convert it to a Flux like this `Flux<String>`. 
In my junior mind I think it should be simple because `Mono<Stream<String>>` is the "hope" for a String and `Flux<String>` is also the "hope" of a String, therefore there should be a simple operator to do the conversion.
I am new to Spring boot webflux, so if there is an operator for this query just show me or tell me why such operation is not possible.

```
Mono<Stream<String>> authoritiesStream = Mono.just(Stream.of(""));
        
Flux<String> authorities = authoritiesStream.???
```

I don't want to collect() the stream and use `flatMapIterable()` to do the conversion because collecting would imply that I have lost my asynch edge. Please teach me

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Problem is not with Mono to Flux, The actual problem i think is with Steam<String> to String.
Ignore Mono and Flux for a moment .

How are you going to convert Stream<String> to String first ?

Comment: can you use `Flux.fromStream(...)`?

Comment: @Alex , i don't think it solves the problem, Flux.fromStream accepts Stream as input not Mono<Stream<Obj>>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what is the idea behind `Mono<Stream<String>>` but assuming you are getting it from another method you could do something like

```
Flux<String> authorities = authoritiesStream
    .flatMapMany(stream -> Flux.fromStream(stream));
```